Should shishya learn only by staying in Guru's house?
I read in Vishnu smriti that student should stay in Guru's house to learn Vidya..But now a days it is hard..Are there any examples in scriptures which show that students did sadhana by staying in their homes(not their Guru's home)?
Thanks

Ramayan and Mahabharat are 2 such examples, where Rama and his brothers or Pandav & Kauravs did there learning at guru's ashram, even Krishna & his brother for that matter.

I mean in their own home not in their guru's home

In last 100-150 years, this is the common pattern:

Yogi Shyamacharan Lahiri ji did sadhana at home, in Varanasi.

You may read in detail in - Autobiography of Yogi by Paramhansa Yoganand.

Swami Vivekannand ji and other disciples of Paramhansa Ramakrishna, did sadhana at home. They would meet RK at temple frequently.

